# How do I calculate weight/number average relative molecular mass for polymers?

Tags: polymers, materials

I have to estimate the weight/number average relative molecular mass of following diagram:

[image]

I know the equations:

[image]

I just can't interpret the diagram. Do I use the chain length as mass of the individual polymer?

I would then get $\pu{M_w = 52.305}$
and  $\pu{M_n = 68.227}$

Is this alright? I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

They perhaps want you to make the calculations *relatively*, which means that even if you assume by looking at the first graph that the mass of the molecular chain length of $1$ (taken relatively and not as per scale) is $x$ units and thus, the mass of $10$ (again, taken relatively and not as per scale) such chains add up to $10x$ units and finally calculate $M_n$ to be $\approx 68.2273x$ it isn't helping us to get a meaningful answer.

A thing that should be noted is that even if you calculate it by following my example, when you'll finally calculate $\displaystyle \frac{M_w}{M_n}$ which (perhaps) the questioner wants you to calculate it won't make difference because this result is independent of $x$.

---

It appears that the questioner hasn't explicitly stated the mass of a polymer chain or that of the monomer units. They even haven't stated that all the polymers are considered identical with respect; it is highly probable that they want you to assume these things so as not to make things overly complicated.